# Populate bootstrap select with Json data And Knockout JS Viewmodel

Tags: json, knockout.js

I am using JSON and bootstrap controls in my project. In my JSON I retrieve data from my `sql database`. Now I want to populate my select control with my data but it doesn't work, I can't see what I am doing wrong and I have searched lots of fiddles to get it to work.

This is my JSON ::

```
    var Projectss = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.ProjectName = ko.observable(data.ProjectName);
    }

    var ProjectModel = function (Projects) {
        var self = this;
        self.Projects = ko.observableArray(Projects);

    $.ajax({
            url: "CreateTask.aspx/GetProjectList",
            // Current Page, Method  
            data: '{}',
            // parameter map as JSON  
            type: "POST",
            // data has to be POSTed  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // posting JSON content      
            dataType: "JSON",
            // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
            timeout: 10000,
            // AJAX timeout  
            success: function (Result) {
                var MappedProjects =
              $.map(Result.d,
       function (item) { return new Projectss(item); });
                self.Projects(MappedProjects);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }

        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var VM = new ProjectModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM);
    })

</script>
```

This is where I am trying to populate my select, this is inside of my td

```
div data-bind="foreach: Projects">
 select data-bind="options: $root.MappedProjects, optionsText: ProjectName, value: 'ProjectName'">
/select>
/div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `optionsText` [select binding option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) you need to specify your property name as string so you need to write `'ProjectName'` (note the single quotes).

However the [`value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) needs the property itself so you need to write `ProjectName` (note there are no quotes).

So the fixed binding looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Projects">
    <select data-bind="options: $root.MappedProjects, 
                       optionsText: 'ProjectName', value: ProjectName">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fixed the binding like told but it doesn't work. I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/N7J2E/ with the Json data but it still does not work. Could you please assist me if possible

Comment: @G-Man I've fixed up your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/nBCwj/. But there were lots of error in your binding. You had `"options: $root.items optionstext: items.ProjectName"`. Where the correct binding is `"options: $root.items, optionsText: 'ProjectName'"`  a comma was missing and also bindings are case sensitive. And your mapping plugin usage was plain wrong. I strongly recommend that you read the documentation and some examples about knockout in general and the ko mapping plugin. By the way the manual mapping code what you had in your question was more follow-able and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way to populate a select with knockout:

HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
    Select Query:
    <select id="QueryName" data-bind="options: Data, optionsText: 'QueryName', value: QueryName, event: { 'change': vm.LoadQuery }">
    </select>
</div>
```

Can add an event to load data on change by adding the following: `event: { 'change': vm.LoadQuery }`

Knockout:

```
vm = {
        Data: ko.observableArray(),
     }

    function LoadQueries() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ExportCustomQueriesList.aspx/GetQueries",
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function (response) {
                vm.Data(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)));
                ko.applyBindings(vm);

                //var n = noty({ text: 'Query in progress of execution', theme: 'default', layout: 'center', timeout: 2000, type: 'error' });
            }
        })
    }
```